# JLink RTT Driver

Tags: bare-metal, nxp-microcontroller, segger-jlink

How can I add RTT driver in my bare metal code. Do you know any tutorial for this? The Jlink RTT driver needs to be defined as a "dev/console" because of middleware want to console.

I want to add Jlink RTT driver as a console in my project.